# Why are pyinstaller executable files using xlwings or openpyxl over 30x larger than xlrd

Tags: python, excel, pyinstaller, xlrd, xlwings

I am using Python 3.7 (Anaconda install) to process an Excel file to create a Word document.

I wrote a script file to do this using xlwings and python-docx which works correctly when executing the script from my Python environment. However, when trying to create an executable for people using Pyinstaller (more specifically auto-py-to-exe) it produces a very large executable file (> 300 mb), which takes a very long time to create the exe and long to run the exe file.

I created 3x test scripts using python-docx with xlrd, openpyxl, or xlwings to create a word document, read a single cell from test file 'testEXCEL.xlsx' and write/save it to a word document.

XLRD Test: 9 mb file

```
#Using auto-py-to-exe single file produces 9 mb exe file
from docx import Document
import xlrd

document = Document()
document.add_paragraph('Testing')

wb = xlrd.open_workbook('testEXCEL.xlsx')
ws = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
testvalue = ws.cell_value(0,0)

document.add_paragraph(testvalue)
document.save('testDOCX_xlrd.docx')
```

XLWINGS Test: 329 mb

```
#Using auto-py-to-exe single file produces 329 mb exe file
from docx import Document
import xlwings as xw

document = Document()
document.add_paragraph('Testing')

wb = xw.Book('testEXCEL.xlsx')
ws = wb.sheets.active
testvalue = ws.range('A1').value

document.add_paragraph(testvalue)
document.save('testDOCX_xlwings.docx')
```

OPENPYXL Test: 329 mb file

```
#Using auto-py-to-exe single file produces 329 mb exe file
from docx import Document
from openpyxl import load_workbook

document = Document()
document.add_paragraph('Testing')

wb = load_workbook('testEXCEL.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
testvalue = ws.cell(1,1).value

document.add_paragraph(testvalue)
document.save('testDOCX_openpyxl.docx')
```

The XLRD version takes < 2 minutes to create the exe and a few seconds to execute the file.
The OPENPYXL and XLWINGS version takes about 20 minutes to create the exe and over a minute to execute the file.

All 3 of the executables from these simple tests work correctly.

The time to create the exectuable, file size, and run time of the executable for XLWINGS seems very high for such a simple example.

Can anyone explain this behavior? 
Is there a way to get a more reasonably sized executable file using XLWINGS or with better performance?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you are using the one file mode, right?

So if there are many files / shared libraries, then for executing the script they have to be extracted to a temporary directory before doing so.

You could create a one directory solution and pack it with a small installer.
This should execute much faster .

If libraries have too many dependencies, then the compilation time will stay high.

I think you can guide pyinstaller to ignore certain files if you're sure, that you do not need them.

Comment: @gelonida I was using one file mode for the original post. Going to one directory does speed up the time to create the executable by about half and the run time of the executables are faster (not fast, lol). The folder size also went up to ~900 mb from 325 mb of openpyxl and xlwings. The xlwings version causes the excel file to physical open and doesn't close, which wasn't experienced with the python script or the single file executable. I don't have enough knowledge about pyinstaller to know what files I can ignore (any references on that topic?).

Comment: Strange! Normally one file mode works less reliable than one directory mode and not vice versa.

If you manage a very small example that fails with onedirmode and works with one file mode you might post it to the pyinstaller team.

About what files to remove? No idea, but yo could try to look for the biggest files in the directory move it away and see whether your script still works.

But if I understand at the moment the onedirmode is not completely operational.